# Смысловые нюансы употребления точки с запятой в заголовке статьи

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика, тире, двоеточие, точка-с-запятой

Меняется ли смысл заголовка статьи, если используется точка с запятой, двоеточие или тире? Поясню вопрос на примере:

1. "Как оформить заявление; образец"
2. "Как оформить заявление: образец"
3. "Как оформить заявление — образец"

Если меняется, то каким образом?

Comment: А если быть проще и понятней: *Образец  заявления*? Есть некоторая нестыковка по смыслу: если вы обещаете объяснить как это делать, то одного лишь образца недостаточно.

Comment: Но это ж не заголовок будет - "образец заявления") Да и суть будет искажена. В статье именно пишется, как оформить и прилагается образец для скачивания.
Статья для юридического сайта. "Заявление" - это я сократила для ясности. А в полном виде там еще будет довольно много слов, к примеру,  "заявление на  выплату алиментов в случае..."

Comment: Если образец не находится в ценре статьи, то почему он заголовке? Я бы его убрал. Но если Вы настаиваете, то едиственный компромисный вариант, по-моему, — скобки: *Как оформить заявление (образец)*, хотя мне это не по душе.

Comment: @Alex_ander предложил сегментированный заголовок с точкой. Это даже лучше, чем со скобками.

Answer (score 2):

Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь:

https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827544.html

Если статья содержит и рекомендации, и образец, логично выбрать сегментированный заголовок с точкой:

> Как оформить заявление. Образец

Третий вариант из вами предложенных подходит для случая, когда приводится только образец.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил.